# Mysql deadlock detection

Tags: mysql, database-deadlocks

Does MySQL always detects the deadlocks automatically? Or the are some situations when MySQL just can't figure out that it's dealing with deadlock?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [MySQL Deadlock Detection via PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554432/mysql-deadlock-detection-via-php)

Comment: Which storage engine are you using? InnoDB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs, MyISAM, a table-level locking storage engine, is [deadlock-free](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html).

InnoDB has [deadlock detection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlock-detection.html).

NDB detection is implemented through a timeout. You can set the [TransactionDeadlockDetectionTimeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-ndbd-definition.html) parameter for transactions.

So, whether its with roll backs or timeouts, the deadlock will eventually recover.

Answer (score 0):

i think it depends upon which engine you are using like innodb can do this automatically.

more explanation is [here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlock-detection.html)