# To what extend is table design responsible for the occurrence of deadlocks?

Tags: mysql, database-deadlocks

We often get the error `SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction`. Some websites show a solution by simply retrying with a try/catch, such as [MySQL Deadlock Detection via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554432/mysql-deadlock-detection-via-php).
My question now is; to what extend is table design responsible for the occurrence of such deadlocks? In particular I am interested in the following example.

```
Table A
  - id (int, primary key)
  - a  (int, foreign key -- references B.a)
  - b  (int, foreign key -- also references B.a)
Table B
  - id (int, primary key)
  - type (enum)
  - a  (int)
```

A record in table `A` may contain a value for `A.a` and `A.b` which both may or may not reference the same record in table `B`. Suppose the deadlock occurs on an insert in table A, can the cause of the deadlock be due to acquiring a lock twice for the same table? Will the amount of deadlocks be less if we split table `B` into a table `B` and a table `B'`, based on the value of `type`? In your answer please don't argue about bad design.

Answer (score 0):

1. > Some websites show a solution by simply retrying with a try/catch

   One should *always* write application code that handles deadlocks, and the usual approach is indeed to simply retry the transaction.  As documented under [How to Cope with Deadlocks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-deadlocks.html):

   > [Deadlocks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/glossary.html#glos_deadlock) are a classic problem in transactional databases, but they are not dangerous unless they are so frequent that you cannot run certain transactions at all. Normally, you must write your applications so that they are always prepared to re-issue a transaction if it gets rolled back because of a deadlock.
   >
   > `[ deletia ]`
   >
   > You can cope with deadlocks and reduce the likelihood of their occurrence with the following techniques:
   >
   > `[ deletia ]`
   >
   > - Always be prepared to re-issue a transaction if it fails due to deadlock. Deadlocks are not dangerous. Just try again.
2. > to what extend is table design responsible for the occurrence of such deadlocks?

   Table design is of course be a contributing factor, but I would rarely be motivated to remodel my schema (except by introducing appropriate indexes if they are not present) purely because of deadlocks.  Certainly it would not be my first remedy.

   Instead, excessive deadlocks can usually be resolved in one's application code: by ensuring that guilty transactions acquire locks in a consistent order; by reducing the size of transactions so that they are committed and their locks released ASAP; or by utilising a lower isolation level.  Failing that, one can always *serialise* one's transactions.
3. > Suppose the deadlock occurs on an insert in table `A`, can the cause of the deadlock be due to acquiring a lock twice for the same table?

   No: locks are held by the *session*; once the session holds a lock, it doesn't need to reacquire it.
4. > Will the amount of deadlocks be less if we split table B into a table B and a table B', based on the value of type?

   I cannot think of any reason why such a redesign alone would *reduce* deadlocks, although it could potentially *increase* them (entails more records overall, requiring more locks).